# IntelliJ runs wrong Spring Boot class

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm working on a Spring Boot project with IntelliJ IDEA (2021.3.1, community edition). I have two classes annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. One's the main application, and the other is a utility for helping build up the database I'm using.

I've been trying to run the utility from IntelliJ with an Application configuration. I have the utility class specified in that configuration as the one to run. But IntelliJ runs the main application class instead.

I tried taking the `@SpringBootApplication` off my main class, and then the run configuration would run the utility. I put the annotation back on my main class, and the run configuration ran the utility *and* the main class.

I am absolutely stumped. Is "Application" the wrong kind of run configuration? Is there something else I need to be setting up to get it to run the right class?

Comment: You need to use "Spring Boot" run configuration. See https://i.imgur.com/6mLkGDR.jpg

Comment: It is available in Ultimate version only though.